# How insert the outline (the bookmarks) into DjVu

Tags: djvu

How insert the outline (the bookmarks) into DjVu file for easier browsing in a document using the [DjVuLibre](http://djvu.sourceforge.net/) library?

With such a structure:

- "TOC" **level 1** => link to *pageNumber*
- "Chapter name" **level 1** => link to *pageNumber*

  - "Chapter name" **level 2** => link to *pageNumber*
- "Chapter name" **level 1** => link to *pageNumber*

  - "Chapter name" **level 2** => link to *pageNumber*

    - "Chapter name" **level 3** => link to *pageNumber*
- "Chapter name" **level 1** => link to *pageNumber*
  ...

Answer (score 4):

**First, create your desired structure in a text editor.**

On the first line will be placed keyword `bookmarks` in round brackets as a root.

Behind the chapter titles are located page numbers or page names (with a suffix `.djvu`). Before the number must be symbol sharp `#`. All parameters are enclosed in quotation marks `""`.

Lower order chapters are created by embedding additional round brackets behind higher order chapter.

Sample with page numbers:

```
(bookmarks
    ("TOC" "#3")
    ("Chapter 1 - Blabla" "#7"
        ("Subchapter 1.1 - Blabla" "#11")
    )
    ("Chapter 2 - Blabla" "#15"
        ("Subchapter 2.1 - Blabla" "#17"
            ("Subchapter 2.1.1 - Blabla" "#20")
        )
    )
    ("Chapter 3 - Blabla" "#25")
)
```

Sample with page names (with a suffix `.djvu`):

```
(bookmarks
    ("TOC" "#page_0003.djvu")
    ("Chapter 1 - Blabla" "#page_0007.djvu"
        ("Subchapter 1.1 - Blabla" "#page_00011.djvu")
    )
    ("Chapter 2 - Blabla" "#page_00015.djvu"
        ("Subchapter 2.1 - Blabla" "#page_00017.djvu"
            ("Subchapter 2.1.1 - Blabla" "#page_00020.djvu")
        )
    )
    ("Chapter 3 - Blabla" "#page_00025.djvu")
)
```

Caution: Save the file in `UTF-8`.

**Second, paste the created outline text file into the selected DjVu file.**

Install the [DjVuLibre](http://djvu.sourceforge.net/) library (if you do not already have it).
From the library we use `djvused` tool.

At the command prompt, type:

```
path\djvused path\book.djvu -e "set-outline path\outline.txt" -s
```

Instead `path` parameter substitute your location on the disk.
Parameter `-e` is the exec (system call) of the `set-outline` command with the filename parameter.
Parameter `-s` is save command.

Press Enter...

Answer (score 0):

Although the following method does not explicitly use the DjVuLibre library (it does implicitly), the following method might save some of your precious time...

- Use some tool to extract the contents from the djvu file. I recommend [pdf_contents_extractor](https://pypi.org/project/pdf-contents-extractor/) for python3 which can be easily installed with pip(pip3) (only tested on linux, but works for djvu too)
- Fine-tune the contents.txt or contents_ocr.txt file with your favorite text editor
- Use [HandyOutliner](http://handyoutlinerfo.sourceforge.net/) to insert the bookmarks in your djvu file

Comment: I was not able to run HandyOutliner on Linux, and did not even find a [Mono] executable for Linux, even though the program's web page states that it is cross-platform. Would appreciate your help!

Comment: @Maxim which linux distribution are you using?

Comment: Currently -- Mint, which is Debian-based

Comment: I used djvusmooth by Jakub WIlk for years, really liked it, and even added a Wikipedia entry on it, I believe. But it is Python 2-based, with some obsolete/legacy dependencies...

Comment: And mono is not included with Mint (try `sudo apt search mono`). Well otherwise, I guess at least it should be possible to install it from [here](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin). B.t.w. if you are, or planning to become, a GNU/linux power user, then I would strongly recommend you to use [doc-toc](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/doc-toc.html) for Emacs.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I had no difficulty installing Mono in Mint.

The problem is that the HandyOutliner home page only provides a file named HandyOutliner.exe in their Downloads directory

Running a `file` on it gives

`./HandyOutliner.exe: PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386 Mono/.Net assembly, for MS Windows`, and running

`$ mono ./HandyOutliner.exe`

gives some long `[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException...`. I never studied Mono, and gave up...

Thank you so much for your time!!!

Comment: on doc-toc: that you for your suggestion!! -- I switched from emacs to Vim some 13 years ago; my hands could not handle the Escape-Meta-Alt-Control-Shift; I am sure you know this EMACS joke :))

Comment: Haha, I switched from Vim to Emacs about 3 years ago, and I completely understand the joke about the keybindings:) But I am just using Vim inside Emacs (it is called evil-mode). I started with using Spacemacs, which you could [take a look at](https://develop.spacemacs.org/doc/BEGINNERS_TUTORIAL.html) (I have created a [toc layer](https://github.com/dalanicolai/toc-layer) for it also). As a Vim user, you will be immediately able to use it, and see what Emacs all has to offer. Actually, the main reason I switched to Emacs is that Emacs made it ridiculously easy to create doc-toc.