# How to edit the bookmarks of a DjVu file

Tags: djvu

I know how to add bookmarks into a DjVu file:

- [How insert the outline (the bookmarks) into DjVu](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/7866/how-insert-the-outline-the-bookmarks-into-djvu)
- https://superuser.com/questions/1170248/how-to-embed-bookmarks-to-djvu-file-using-djvused-djvulibre

But how do I edit existing bookmarks? Do I need to re-insert a modified bookmark file? If so, is there a way to extract the bookmarks into a text file, edit the text file, and re-insert the bookmarks into the DjVu file?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to extract existing bookmarks to a file, edit it, and then set it back (old bookmarks will be overwriten):

```
# extract bookmarks
djvused -e "print-outline" my.djvu > bookmarks.txt

# edit bookmarks.txt

# set bookmarks back to document
djvused -s -e "set-outline bookmarks.txt" my.djvu
```

You may also find some GUI tools that will allow you to edit bookmarks, but basically they do the replacement under the hood.

Comment: Is there a GUI tool you know of? Djvusmooth is obsolete, alas...

Comment: never tried any of them. Perhaps [Pdf & DjVu Bookmarker](https://sourceforge.net/projects/djvubookmarker/)

Comment: truf -- that's a Windows-only tool :(

Comment: may be https://sourceforge.net/projects/handyoutlinerfo/

Comment: thank you for your comment! Even though the web page for the handyoutliner claims that their program is cross-platform, they only provide the Windows executable in their downloads! Very unfair... -- Thank you again! -- m.

Comment: @Maxim, well it still does work, at least it could be lauched. Didn't checked it after GUI has been started. On a morden linux you need to istall a few packages`sudo apt install mono-runtime libmono-system-windows-forms4.0-cil`, then download and unpack app archieve, Then grant "start-linux" script execution rights with `chmod +x ./start-linux`. Then launch it with `./start-linux`.
The executable is a .NET code so it can be launched on Linux with mono in some cases.

Comment: thank you so so much for taking your time and explaining everything in detail!

I was able to run the HandyOutliner after installing libmono-system-windows-forms4.0-cil, as you suggested. 

I got an error with the first DjVu file I tried the program with: it already has a partial outline I created previously with DjvuSmooth which uses UTF-8 (this particular outline needs Cyrillic characters); the Handy outliner produced an error stating that it would only take the (legacy) Windows 1251 encoding for the Cyrillic. So I gave up... Might try it on another file where the outline will be

Comment: (continuation) where the outline will be in English; but I regularly use three languages for creating outlines; and forcing WIndows encoding in 2023 seems strange...) (It did not even agree to open the file to erase the current TOC and create a new one!)

Otherwise, did I understand correctly that you are the author of the legendary Scantailor? If so, may I drop you a line? 

Thank you again!

Comment: @Maxim Legendary scantailor's author is Joseph Artsimovich. I'm just maintaining one of its forks (Universal), and not the most popular (Advanced) one. You may drop me a line, but I barely have a time to do anything related to djvu nowadays. Also you may better to ask about GUI tools [here](http://forum.ru-board.com/topic.cgi?forum=5&topic=51044) or [here](http://publ.lib.ru/cgi/forum/YaBB.pl?board=format). I'm pretty sure these guys know all existing djvu tools.